# How can I put a Java array inside itself?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm attempting to create a Java object array and place the array inside itself at its second index (in order to represent a self-similar fractal with the array), but when I try to access `theArray[1][1][0]`, I get this error:

`Main.java:11: error: array required, but Object found`.

This is what I've tried so far, and I'm not sure why it's not working:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Object[] theArray = new Object[2];
        theArray[0] = "This array should contain itself at its second index.";
        theArray[1] = theArray; //Now I'm attempting to put the array into itself.
        System.out.println(theArray[1][1][0]) //Main.java:11: error: array required, but Object found
    }
}
```

Is it actually possible to put a Java array inside itself, as I'm attempting to do here?

Comment: Hint: Read up on the Java `instanceof` operator. You'll need that.

Comment: You could use `((Object[])((Object[])theArray[1])[1])[0]` :)

Comment: @Eng.Fouad That reminds me of some obfuscation I've seen that collapsed everything into `Object[]` instances, resulting in wild series of casts; it definitely is a bit obscure at first sight.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`theArray[1]` is of *compile-time* type `Object` (since it comes from an array of **Objects**).

You need to cast it to `Object[]` to use it as an array.

---

The fundamental problem you're encountering is that although an array that contains itself is a perfectly valid object, it isn't a valid *type*.

You can nest array types arbitrarily deeply – `Object[][][][][][][][][][][][][]` is a valid type.
However, the "bottom level" of the type can't be an array.

You're trying to create a type which is an array of *itself*.
Using generics, that would be possible:

```
class Evil extends ArrayList<Evil> { }
```

Comment: Right.  An element of your `Object[]` array is, to the compiler, just an `Object`.  It needs to be cast to `Object[]` using the `(Object[])` cast operation.  This causes the compiler to generate a runtime check to assure that it really is an `Object[]` the way you say it is.

Comment: @HotLicks: Actually, the runtime check comes from the JITter, I believe.

Comment: `System.out.println((Object[])(theArray[1])[1][0]);` seems to produce the same error.

Comment: @AndersonGreen: That's because `(Object[])(theArray[1])[1]` is also an `Object`.  Can you understand why?

Comment: @AndersonGreen You're just getting the error one array further down now (because it doesn't know that `theArray[1][1]` is an Array...)

Comment: @SLaks - The runtime check is generated by compiler as a `castcheck` bytecode (or is it `checkcast` -- never can remember which).  This bytecode produces a runtime check in the JVM interpreter or in JITCed code.  If the bytecode is omitted the JVM class verifier will complain of the type mismatch, just as the compiler does.

Comment: @HotLicks: I see.  I'm used to C#, which will (I think) emit a single `castclass` instruction, which implies a typecheck.

Comment: @SLaks: strictly speaking you can't nest array types arbitrarily deeply: you can't have any more than 255 dimensions. However, that's not a limitation you're likely to bump into unless you're writing some extremely twisted code.

Comment: @LukeWoodward: I never knew that; thanks! http://ideone.com/IS5yuV  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.11

Comment: @SLaks: looks like you found the reference before I did.  I was spending too long searching around in the JLS when it's actually in the JVM spec.  I was just about to post a link to a SO question but you beat me to it.

Answer (score 2):

You're running into a casting error since you've declared `theArray` to be an Array of Objects. As a result, you can't promise Java that `theArray[1]` is an `Array`--it could be any kind of `Object`. You'll need to break up your access to do what you want:

```
Object[] innerArray = (Object[]) theArray[1];
System.out.println(innerArray[0] == theArray[0]); // Always true since innerArray IS theArray
while (true) {
    // Careful! This loops forever!
    // set innerArray = innerArray[1] = theArray = theArray[1] = innerArray... 
    // all of these are the exact same object (but you have to tell Java their type every time)
    innerArray = (Object[]) innerArray[1]; 
    System.out.println(innerArray[0]);
}
```

Comment: BTW, that will never (AFAIK?) crash.

Comment: It's the same array; it will never run out.  And it won't leak memory or stack, either.

Comment: @SLaks Why would this not run out? Each iteration sets `innerArray` to point to its own second element... unless I've done something stupid without noticing?

Comment: `innerArray[1]` _is_ `innerArray`.

Comment: `innerArray` takes value of `theArray[1]`; `innerArray` takes value of `innerArray[1]`, which is `theArray[1]`, which is `innerArray`. Thus, the line `innerArray = (Object[]) innerArray[1]` actually does nothing, and the loop is, in fact, infinite.

Comment: Thank you guys; I had misinterpreted the OP's setup. I got distracted by the nested-arrays-casting problem and forgot the array actually contained itself.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is equivalent to

```
Object arr = theArray[1];  // arr is an Object here, not an array
```

But you could do

```
Object[] arr = (Object[] ) theArray[1];    // Now it is an array
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done quite easily with ArrayLists:

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
list.add(list);
```

So now

```
System.out.println(list.get(0));
```

and

```
System.out.println(((ArrayList)list.get(0)).get(0)); //Casting because .get() returns an Object
```

Both will output the same thing.

You can take this to an arbitrarily large number of levels, if you want to:

```
        System.out.println(((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)((ArrayList)list.get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0)).get(0));
```