# Is it possible to put a C array inside itself?

Tags: c, arrays

In many programming languages (including [JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16678338/is-it-possible-for-a-javascript-array-to-contain-itself), [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16679101/how-can-i-put-a-java-array-inside-itself), and [Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10606734/what-are-recursive-arrays-good-for)), it's possible to put an array inside itself. Here, I'm trying to put a C integer array inside itself at its 3rd index, but I'm not sure if this is supported in the C programming language:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int arr[] = {1, 1, 2};
    arr[2] = arr; //now I'm trying to put arr into itself.
    printf("%i", arr[2]); //this prints a negative number each time I run the program
    printf("%i", arr[2][0]); //prog.c:7:24: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector

    return 0;
}
```

Is it possible to put a C array inside itself, or is it not possible at all?

Comment: Make a jagged array if you need an array of arrays of different lengths.

Comment: @chris Still, I don't see how that would make it any easier to put the array inside itself.

Comment: You can make an array of void pointers and use lots of typecasting to drive yourself insane... Perhaps what you want instead is a linked list?

Comment: You probably could with an array of void pointers, but ... why?

Comment: @AndersonGreen, It's fairly easy if you assign to a pointer. If you want copies, it's not much more work. The thing is that C is not at all like Java, and definitely not like Ruby or JS. I find newer languages tend to have certain things built in that C doesn't and a lot of them tend to fix things that C makes harder than most languages now, like string operations.

Comment: @John Representing a self-similar fractal is the main use case that I have in mind, since fractals usually contain copies of themselves.

Comment: As Paul suggested, why not use linked lists?

Answer (score 5):

No, it's not possible for an array of `int` to contain itself.

There are some (likely non-portable) tricks you can play, like making one of the elements of the array be a converted pointer to the array:

```
int arr[10];
arr[5] = (int)arr;
```

but this doesn't make the array contain itself. The expression `arr`, since it's of array type, is implicitly converted ("decays") to a pointer to its first element in most contexts, including this one. So, assuming the conversion doesn't lose any information, you can retrieve a pointer to the first element of `arr` by converting `arr[5]` back to type `int*`. Note that this only gives you a pointer to `arr`'s first element; it loses any information about the length of `arr`. And it's very common for an `int*` pointer value not to fit into an `int` without loss of information (on 64-bit systems, it's common for `int*` to be 64 bits and `int` to be 32 bits).

Integers, pointers, and arrays are three very different things. They are not simply interchangeable.

Recommend reading: section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/); it does a very good job of explaining the often confusing relationship between arrays and pointers in C.

Even in languages like Java and Ruby, an array can't actually *contain* itself. It can contain a *reference* to itself -- though the language might provide syntactic sugar that hides the fact that it's a reference. In C, such references are generally explicit.

What you can do is define a data structure that contains a pointer to an object of its own type. This is generally done with structures. For example:

```
struct tree_node {
    int data;
    struct tree_node *left;
    struct tree_node *right;
};
```

This being C, you have to manage memory for your tree nodes explicitly, using `malloc()` to allocate and `free()` to deallocation -- or you can use an existing library that does that for you.

Answer (score 0):

It actually is possible, if the length of an int on your system is equal to or greater than the length of a pointer, such that you can cast the pointer to an int to store it - and if you remember to cast it back before you try to dereference it as a pointer.  Neglecting to do the latter was the cause of your error message.

Note that in such a simple scheme you will have to separately keep track of which elements are values and which are pointers.  Only if you can guarantee that the length of a pointer is less than the length of an element (or that the valid range of a userspace pointer is further constrained) could you reserve some bits to indicate if an element is a literal value or a pointer.

Here's an example of how you might explicitly cast it back, based on prior knowledge that this is what would be appropriate for that element:

```
printf("%i", ((int *)arr[2])[0]);
```

To accomplish this more cleanly, you may want to make an array not of ints, but instead of unions, such that each element is a `union` of an int and a pointer - meaning there are two formally recognized possible views of the same memory.  But you will still need a scheme to keep track of the applicable type of each element.